# sql: detect string containing multiple languages

Tags: sql-server-2012

Column `[Plate_No]` in `[my_Table]` contains vehicle plate numbers for Greek and foreign vehicles. Generally Greek plate numbers contain only Greek characters, and foreign plates contain only Latin characters.

Now, some rows contain plate numbers with mixed characters and is incorrect.

for example:

```
DECLARE @my_Plates AS TABLE (
   Plate_No NVARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @my_Plates (
    Plate_No
)
SELECT 'AAA1234'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ΑΑΑ1234'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'AΑA1234'

SELECT Plate_No, LOWER(Plate_No) AS LC_Plate_No
FROM @my_Plates
```

result:

```
Plate_No | LC_Plate_No
---------------------
AAA1234  | aaa1234      <-- correct
ΑΑΑ1234  | ααα1234      <-- correct
AΑA1234  | aαa1234      <-- incorrect
```

As you can see plate numbers are visually the same, but when LOWER applied, the difference is obvious.

How can those incorrect rows be detected ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I edited your sample data insert statement to make it produce the output in the result section - the original didn't work for me.

Comment: strange thing. copy and paste from stackoverflow to my SSMS works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one method which works when the column collation is `Greek_CI_AS`:

```
DECLARE @my_Plates AS TABLE (
   Plate_No NVARCHAR(50) COLLATE Greek_CI_AS
)

INSERT INTO @my_Plates (
    Plate_No
)
SELECT UPPER(N'aaa1234')
UNION ALL
SELECT UPPER(N'ααα1234')
UNION ALL
SELECT UPPER(N'aαa1234')

SELECT  Plate_No, LOWER(Plate_No) 
FROM    @my_Plates
WHERE   Plate_No <> CAST(Plate_No AS varchar(50)) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
AND     Plate_No LIKE '%[A-Z]%'
```

this probably won't perform well on large data sets - neither of the `WHERE` conditions will be able to use an index on `Plate_No`.

Comment: this does not return any row from my example.

Comment: @armen - both this and the differences we experienced copy/pasting from the sample code in the question suggest that there might be a difference in the collation settings of our environments. What does `exec sp_helpsort` return for you?

Comment: Greek, case-insensitive, accent-sensitive, kanatype-insensitive, width-insensitive

Comment: @armen - see my update. I was able to replicate the behaviour you saw by setting the collation of `Plate_No`, and have amended my answer to resolve it.

Comment: thank you, it worked fine. although I just found another way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

here's a workaround using `LIKE`. It's heavy for 10.000.000+ rows, but it's OK since it's only a one time check for correction.

```
SELECT
Plate_No
, LOWER(Plate_No) AS LC_Plate_No
, (
    CASE WHEN Plate_No LIKE '%[α-ω]%' AND Plate_No LIKE '%[a-z]%'
        THEN '0'
        ELSE '1'
    END
) AS isCorrect
FROM @my_Plates
```